# python adding a space when using logging

Tags: python, logging

I'm having an issue with the python package logging. I'm trying to generate a CEF event log using:

```
my_logger = logging.getLogger('Logger')
my_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address = (IP,514))
my_logger.addHandler(handler)
my_logger.info('CEF:0|test|test|1.0|100|test|0|msg=test')
```

When I perform this, the syslog server receives:

> Dec 28 09:18:39 testhost CEF: 0|test|test|1.0|100|test|0|msg=test

I believe the log isn't able to be parsed and the log is dropped as a result. Is there anyway to prevent the space from being inserted into the message?

Comment: It probably has to do with the SysLogHandler. rsyslog events have an event type and that is probably being parsed out from the CEF and appended to the program name or something like that.

Comment: Well, I got a little further into it. When I dump the net traffic, I don't see the space. I can't blame python logging at this point. I'm going to check to see if there might be some issue with the parser now. Thanks.